# Add a loader for authentication flow on React Native Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I just added the loader that is loaded when the user sends the request to login by clicking the button with this code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, TextInput, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Image, KeyboardAvoidingView, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import {AuthContext} from './utils';

// Creating Login Activity.
export function SignInScreen() {

    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const [email, setEmail] = React.useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');

    const { signIn } = React.useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={Platform.OS == 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'} style={styles.keyboard_login}>
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.contenitore_login}>
              {isLoading == true ? <ActivityIndicator size="large"/> : (
                <>
                <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('../assets/logo.png')} />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.campo_login}
                    placeholder="Email"
                    value={email}
                    onChangeText={setEmail}
                    autoCapitalize='none'
                    textContentType='emailAddress'
                    keyboardType='email-address'
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.campo_login}
                    placeholder="Password"
                    value={password}
                    onChangeText={setPassword}
                    secureTextEntry
                />
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.cta_login} onPress={() => { setLoading(true); signIn({ email, password });}}>
                    <Text style={styles.testo_cta_login}>Accedi</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                </>
              )}
            </SafeAreaView>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
}
```

Everything works perfectly when the user enters the correct email and password, but when they enter the wrong credentials the loader keeps going.

```
}).then((response) => response.json()).then((responseJson) => {
              // If server response message same as Data Matched
              if(responseJson === 'Data Matched'){
                  dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN', token: 'dummy-auth-token' });
              }else{
                  Alert.alert(responseJson);
              }
        }).catch((error) => {
              console.error(error);
        });
```

As you can see if the fetch URL says "Data Matched" then it is assigned SIGN_IN which then returns the user to the home of my app, but in the case where the logins don't match I don't know what to do to send the user back to the login page.

What is the navigation code that is used in this case? Thanks!

Comment: You can have variable let's say `fetching : false(initially)`. Set it to `true` in your signin function starting and `false` at the end.

Comment: @Rohit Will this solve my problem? Can you write an example code in the answer? It would be greatly appreciated, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

We can have variable let's say `loading`

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
```

And as far I can see your Sigin function connects to db. So do something like

```
const authContext = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      signIn: async data => {
                    setLoading(true);
                    // Some code here

                    setLoading(false);
               }
           })
)
```

And then show an Activity indicator or any component you want to show fetching something like this

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {View, ActivityIndicator, Modal} from 'react-native';
import styles from './Styles/FullScreenLoaderStyles';

const FullScreenLoader = ({loading}) => (
  <Modal transparent={true} animationType={'none'} visible={loading}>
    <View style={styles.modalBackground}>
      <View style={styles.activityIndicatorWrapper}>
        <ActivityIndicator color="#000" animating={loading} />
      </View>
    </View>
  </Modal>
);

FullScreenLoader.propTypes = {
  loading: PropTypes.bool,
};

export default FullScreenLoader;
```

I have updated the loading screen code. Now you can import this in your google signin screen like

```
import FullScreenLoader from './FullScreenLoader';
// some code
return(
   <View>
     <FullScreenLoader loading={isLoading} />
   </View>
)
FullScreenLoaderStyles.js
```

```
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import colors from '../../Themes/Colors';

export default StyleSheet.create({
  modalBackground: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#00000040',
  },
  activityIndicatorWrapper: {
    backgroundColor: colors.grey,
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Unfortunately it still doesn't work though. Maybe I'm skipping some steps. This is my code for ActivityIndicatorScreen: https://pastebin.com/MxgY9bzF and this is my code for App.js: https://pastebin.com/q3dw3EWU

Comment: @MatteoFeduzi I'll surely look after the issue.

Comment: Thanks, found the problem?

Comment: @MatteoFeduzi I have updated the code accordingly. I have added the code in modal and this can be set to true while fetching. Being transparent it gives the user interface for loading.

Comment: I don't understand where I should put this code:return(
   <View>
     <FullScreenLoader loading={fetching} />
   </View>
)

Comment: Then I was thinking: isn't it better to use directly the variable "isLoading" present under the various CASE?

Comment: Put this code in your screen where you want to show the loading. For example in your SignInScreen.js

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately still no solution. Then I thought: why doesn't it already use the "isLoading" which is attributed in CASE? Couldn't I just use that directly? I did not understand why your example uses an additional loading variable

Comment: I have changed the code. Sorry for the variable name conflicts. If the issue still persists, can you please share GitHub or code sandbox link?

Comment: Can you tell me if in the fetch I posted here: https://pastebin.com/q3dw3EWU you can apply an additional control that says: "if you're waiting for a response call a function that shows the loader"?

Comment: Perhaps the best solution is to use render?